# Change format of dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to write a function that takes a dictionary with the following format write them in to a csv file that has columns for each test (the keys in the first dictionary), and rows for different pollutants (the keys in the sub-dictionaries) that are being tested and. Each cell will contain the value of the sub-dictionary.

```
output=table.csv
dictionaryEx={'run2.csv': {' ph': 25, ' escherichia coli': 14, ' enterococci': 1},
 'run1.csv': { ' enterococci': 7, ' ph': 160, ' nickel': 3, 
 ' dieldrin': 4, ' barium': 1, ' trichloroethylene': 1, }


def writeFile(dictionary)
    with open(output,'w') as outputFile:
    polDict={}
    for element in dictionary:
        print element
        for pollutant,value in element.values():
            polDict[pollutant]={element:value}
    for element in polDict:
        outputFile.write(pollutant+','+ polDict.values())
outputFile.close()
```

Now, I trying to accomplish this by making a new dictionary, but am running in to issues with writing from it. Would another data structure be better to work with?
how the csv should look

> "" ,run2.csv,run1.csv\n ph,25,160\n escherichia coli,14,""\n enterococci,1,7\n nickel,"",3

[image]

Comment: You should first of all fix the indentation. Have you tried this example in a Python IDLE? You also don't need to close the file at the end, because **with open** will do it for you.

Comment: why don't you just use the `csv` module that works with `dictionaries` just fine (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)?

Comment: Sorry, but can you show what the resulting csv would look like? Likely, this would be pretty straightforward with the `csv` module, but it's better to be explicit with the .csv you are expecting.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am not familar with the csv module but will look in to it. I will also put a screenshot of the excel version of the csv in case what I typed is not clear

Comment: Do you care about the order in either dimension? That is, does `ph` need to be the first row of data, and `tricholoroethylene` the last, or do you not care? How about the order of the rows? (I'm guessing you don't care since run2 is ahead of run1, but perhaps that's an error?) Also, are you using Python 2 or Python 3 (the code required for the `csv` module is slightly different between them).

Comment: it does not matter! thanks for checking

Comment: @Blckknght also I am using python 2 I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar, but shorter

```
cols = dictionaryEx.keys()
rows = set()
for v in dictionaryEx.values():
    rows.update(v.keys()

with open('outputfile','w') as file:
    file.write(',' + ','.join(cols) + '\n')
    for r in sorted(rows):
        file.write(r + ",")
        file.write(",".join([str(d,get(r,"")) for d in dictionaryEx.values()]))
        file.write("\n")
```

Should get this in output file

```
,run2.csv,run1.csv
 barium,,1
 dieldrin,,4
 enterococci,1,7
 escherichia coli,14,
 nickel,,3
 ph,25,160
 trichloroethylene,,1
```

Answer (score 0):

This version works for me with Python 3.5.1:

```
output="table.csv"
dictionaryEx={\
        'run2.csv': {' ph': 25, ' escherichia coli': 14, ' enterococci': 1},\
        'run1.csv': {' enterococci': 7, ' ph': 160, ' nickel': 3, ' dieldrin': 4, ' barium': 1, ' trichloroethylene': 1}}

def writeFile(dictionary):
    with open(output,'w') as outputFile:
        # Write the title line.
        outputFile.write(",")
        for key in dictionary.keys():
            outputFile.write(key + ",")
        outputFile.write("\n")

        # Generate a sorted unique list of pollutants.
        pollutants = []
        for d in dictionary.values():
            for k in d.keys():
                pollutants.append(k)
        # This sorts the list and removes duplicates.
        pollutants = sorted(set(pollutants))

        # For each possible pollutant, output the pollutant's
        # value for each CSV.
        for p in pollutants:
            outputFile.write(p + ",")
            for csv in dictionary.keys():
                if p in dictionary[csv]:
                    outputFile.write(str(dictionary[csv][p]))
                outputFile.write(",")
            outputFile.write("\n")

writeFile(dictionaryEx)
```

Here is the output, which appears properly formatted when I open it in Excel:

```
,run2.csv,run1.csv,
 barium,,1,
 dieldrin,,4,
 enterococci,1,7,
 escherichia coli,14,,
 nickel,,3,
 ph,25,160,
 trichloroethylene,,1,
```